# Getting NaN from Angular service map

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, nan, angular-services

I am consuming an API that returns data from Harry Potter characters like this

### Data from the Endpoint

```
    "name": "Harry Potter",
    "species": "human",
    "gender": "male",
    "dateOfBirth": "31-07-1980",
    "yearOfBirth": 1980,
    "eyeColour": "green",
    "hairColour": "black",
    "wand": {
        "wood": "holly",
        "core": "phoenix feather"
    },
    "patronus": "stag",
    "hogwartsStudent": true,
    "hogwartsStaff": false,
    "actor": "Daniel Radcliffe",
    "alive": true,
    "image": "http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/images/harry.jpg"
},
```

With that info, I want to display a list of characters but with just a few of those properties: name,patronus, age, and image, with that proposal I made the next...

### TypeScript interface:

```
export interface Character {
    name: string;
    patronus: string;
    dateOfBirth: string;
    image: string;
    age: number;
}
```

in the **service** I have the next

### service method:

```
getStudents() {
return this.http.get<Character[]>(this.baseUrl + 'students').pipe(
  map( response => 
    response.map(
      respItem => (
        {
          name: respItem.name,
          patronus: respItem.patronus,
          dateOfBirth: respItem.dateOfBirth,
          image: respItem.image,
          age: new Date().getFullYear()  -  new Date(respItem.dateOfBirth).getFullYear() 
          
        }
        
      )
    ) 
  )

);
```

}

as you can see in the service I'm using map to get the age subtracting the years of DateOfBirth to the years of today's date. (I know I have to make some more in order to know if the birthday of the student has already passed or not but that's not the point of my question).

**The point is that some are coming fine and some others are coming as NaN**
[image]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-students',
  templateUrl: './students.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./students.component.css']
})
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {

  students: Character[]= [];
  
  constructor(private hogwartsService: HogwartsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getStudents();
  }

  getStudents(){
    this.hogwartsService.getStudents().subscribe(response => {
      this.students = response;
      console.log(this.students);
    });
  }
}
```

**So Why is it happening? why some are coming as numbers and others are coming as NaN?**

Comment: it would be helpful if you also posted what the data feed looks like that has the date that worked along with the date that diddn't

Comment: Probably becaus the dateOfBirth string is not in a valid format. You’re better of using yourOfBirth for the calculation..

Comment: @Kinglish I posted the data from the endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Because the passed date format `31-07-1980` is wrong. You should pass like this `MM-DD-YYYY`. So you need to format the `dateOfBirth` before pass it to `Date()`

[Javascript DateTime Formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```js
// NaN
console.log(new Date().getFullYear()  -  new Date("31-07-1980").getFullYear());

// Valid
console.log(new Date().getFullYear()  -  new Date("07-31-1980").getFullYear());
```

**Use Moment.JS**

Using `Moment.JS` you can specify the input date format. It's much more easy to work with multiple date formats.

```
const day = moment("31-07-1980", "DD-MM-YYYY");
```

**Alternative Solution For You**

I found `yearOfBirth` in the provided API response. So why don't you use it to calculate age like this,

```
const age = new Date().getFullYear()  -  respItem.yearOfBirth;
```

Comment: Moment.JS worked Thank you! of course using yearOfBirth also worked, but I will use the entire dateOfBirth to take into consideration if the birthday has passed

Comment: @armandot You are always welcome. Cheers.